# Debug, Unix. Run a program with a different time from the system

Tags: unix

I am debugging a program in MacOSX,
and I need that this program thinks we are one year later than the one given by the operating system.

I cannot change the time of the operation system, because I need to run a second program concurrently with the correct time.
I could modify the code of the first program to add one year each time it gets the time from the operation system, but the code is too big to do that; I prefer not to use this solution.

I heard once that there is a command in Unix to run a program with a fake/mocked time.
Do you know about it?

Comment: If all else fails, you could run it inside a virtual environment and set the time inside that. Last resort though, it's massive overkill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but [libfaketime](http://www.code-wizards.com/projects/libfaketime/) claims to do what you need.

Quoted from the website:

> As an example, we want the "date" command to report our faked time. To do so, we could use the following command line:
>
> ```
> user@host> date
> Tue Nov 23 12:01:05 CEST 2007
>
> user@host> LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libfaketime.so.1 FAKETIME="-15d" date
> Mon Nov  8 12:01:12 CEST 2007
> ```

Assuming the lib works as advertised, you can trick your program into thinking it was running a year ahead using:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libfaketime.so.1 FAKETIME="+1y" ./your_program
```

Comment: Mac OS X uses a different linker, I don't think the environment variable is the same. Try DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES.